# PyCharm: unreachable code in if __debug__

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm says "**This code is unreachable**" for code inside `if __debug__:` statements like

```
if __debug__:
    print("unreachable code is run")
```

which is correctly reached and run.

This is really annoying if declaring debug variables inside that block because PyCharm does not autocomplete for them.

Is this a bug or a messed up configuration?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: The code *is not* reachable when Python is run with ``-O``. PyCharm will correctly auto-complete variables inside the ``__debug__`` block. Are you trying to use the variable somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, but a **not reachable code** warning should appear if code is *never* reachable.

Comment: BTW thanks @MisterMiyagi, yes I'm modifying some variables in debug and reading them outside if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug, please vote for the issue (thumbs up near the title): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29435

Comment: Thanks, so the only thing I can do is to disable the unreachable code inspection or convert it to a *weak warning*, right?

Comment: @Guglie It depends on the usage:(another) separate variable or method could mean that debug mode is enabled, or debugger could be used to evaluate expressions in some particular places

Comment: **2023 update**: should be fixed now in pycharm versions after 2022.2.1